# More efficient way to compute cooccurrence

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to visualise a network of relationships between people.

My data looks like this :

```
let networkData = [
    ["John","Dylan","Brian"],
    ["Dylan","Brian"],
];
```

And I want an output like this :

```
let networkMatrix.links = [
    {source: "John",  target: "Dylan", weight: 1},
    {source: "John",  target: "Brian", weight: 1},
    {source: "Brian", target: "Dylan", weight: 2}
];
```

John and Brian share one group so their weight is 1. The same is true for John and Dylan. As Dylan and Brian share in two groups, their relationship gets a weight of 2.

Now here is where I think I need help. My way of doing that was to go through each line of `networkData`, then through each element of the array. And for each element, go through all the elements that come after, and increment their score in `networkMatrix`. Here is my code.

```
var i = 0, j = 0;
networkData.map(function(d) {
    d.forEach(function(val, ind, tab) {
        for (let k = ind + 1; k < tab.length; k++) {
            while ((i = networkMatrix.person1.indexOf(val, i + 1)) != -1) {
                while ((j = networkMatrix.person2.indexOf(tab[k], j + 1)) != -1) {
                    if (i === j) {
                        networkMatrix.score[i]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0t81jg3b/2/

As you can see it doesn't even work on jsfiddle. But it works more or less on my computer, I don't know why :

[image]

If feel like this is getting waaaaay too complicated for such a simple task, could someone give me some indications on how to get out of this mess?

Comment: Any number of groups? Note you have typos in your demo

Comment: Any number of groups yeah, most probably between 1-100. I'll correct the typos.

Comment: And what is `score`?

Comment: The number of time two people appear in the same group.

Comment: Really not clear how you intend to visualize this. Expected data structure doesn't really make a lot of sense

Comment: I realize, and my final data structure doesn't look like that at all. But I wanted to work on a way to compute `score`before getting into the data structure, and ended up with this monstrosity.

Comment: @charlietfl I edited my post to show the data structure I have.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as follows:

- Only consider name pairs where the source is alphabetically less than the target
- Build a map keyed by source, and for each a nested map keyed by target, and assign a counter to those nested keys. You could use an ES6 `Map` for that, or else plain object

```js
const groupes = [
        ["John", "Dylan", "Brian"],
        ["Dylan", "Brian"],
        ["John", "Kate"]
    ],
    // Get unique list of names
    names = [...new Set([].concat(...groupes))],
    // Create a 2D-map with a counter set to zero
    map = new Map(names.map(name => [name, new Map(names.map(name2 => [name2, 0]))])),
    result = [];

// Count the pairs
for (const groupe of groupes) {
    for (const source of groupe) {
        const targetMap = map.get(source);
        for (const target of groupe) {
            if (source < target) targetMap.set(target, targetMap.get(target)+1);
        }
    }
}

// Convert nested maps to result structure
for (const [source, targetMap] of map.entries()) {
    for (const [target, weight] of targetMap.entries()) {
        if (weight) result.push({source, target, weight}); 
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```